# Cannot connect and update stocks via cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to update the stock and price information of the products in my store with API.

The API library it uses is here: `https://github.com/agtt/epttavm-integration`

With this library, I can list the products and orders in the store.
All these functions are available in the `EPTTAvmLibrary.php` file in the library.

**For example**, when I want to categorize all
I'm using the `KategoriListesi()` function.

```
print_r($EPTT->KategoriListesi());
```

> Output: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object (      [KategoriAdi] => Ev
>   Elektroniği & TV [KategoriId] => 43 )         [1] => stdClass Object ( 
>     [KategoriAdi] => Anne & Bebek & Oyuncak [KategoriId] => 44 )

I would like to update product price and stock information with the same library
The parameter required for my price update,

```
StokGuncelleV2();
```

The Parameter required for my price and stock update

```
StokFiyatGuncelleV3();
```

Both of these parameters are present in the `EPTTAvmLibrary.php` file. However I get the error when using these parameters.
**The code I sent:**

```
$data = (object)array(
    'ShopId' => 'xxxx',
    'Barkod' => 'xxxx',
    'Fiyat' => '14.10',
    'Miktar' => '80',
    'KDVOran' => '18',
    'Iskonto' => '0'
);
print_r($EPTT->StokFiyatGuncelleV3($data));
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   EPTTAvm::StokFiyatGuncelleV3() must be an instance of
>   Epttavm\StokKontrolDetay, instance of stdClass given, called in
>   blabla.com\index.php on line 20 and defined in
>   blabla.com\EPTTAvmLibrary.php:181 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 blabla.com\index.php(20): EPTTAvm->StokFiyatGuncelleV3(Object(stdClass)) #1 {main} thrown in
>
> blabla.com\EPTTAvmLibrary.php on line 181

That's exactly the problem. Could the fields I submit be incorrect?

When I update here, I think this is the relevant piece of code and I send requests to this function. But I don't know if the method of use is correct.

```
EPTTAvmLibrary.php

    /**
     * Update Stock Price,Quantity,TaxRate....
     * @param StokKontrolDetay $data
     * > Required : ShopId , Barkod
     * > Changeables : Fiyat , Miktar , KDV Oranı , Iskonto
     * @return mixed
     */
public function StokFiyatGuncelleV3(StokKontrolDetay $data) {
    try {
        $getData = $this->apiClient->StokFiyatGuncelleV3($data);
        return $getData;
    } catch (EpaException $e) {
        $this->onError($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the error message completely?

Comment: The error is because `$data` is just a generic object, it's not an instance of the `StokKontrolDetay` class, as is required by the method signature (`public function StokFiyatGuncelleV3(StokKontrolDetay $data)`). The error message makes this fairly clear, or so I would have thought. Was there something you didn't understand? Did you try to google the error to get ideas? The solution is to create (and populate) an instance of this `StokKontrolDetay` class and pass it to your method, instead of a generic object.

Comment: @NicoHaase yes I understand the error output. I've tried many different methods but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Mahlika what exactly did you try then? Your code, as provided above, shows no understanding of the error message at all. If you tried to create the class correctly, but failed, please show us that attempt so that we can potentially correct it for you. You may also need to provide us the definition of the class (either code or documentation), so we understand how to construct it and set the property values).

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. I've tried several methods by modifying some classes. The library for this service is here: https://github.com/ePttAVM/api-client, and here explains how to use functions: https://www.odicode.com/webservice.html I just want to use stock and price (StockPriceGuncelleV3).

Comment: @ADyson I've updated the question, I'd appreciate it if you could help. :)

Comment: What does the full stack trace say, exactly? Does it give a specific line of code for the error? From looking at https://github.com/ePttAVM/api-client/blob/master/src/Epttavm/ApiClient.php I can't see how it would ever work like you've shown. There is a method called `StokGuncelle`, but not any method called `StokGuncelleV2` or `StokGuncelleV3`. But also, what is the `SoapClient` class? That does not appear in the source code you provided at all. Are you sure you gave us the right link for the source code?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot speak whatever language https://www.odicode.com/webservice.html is written in (Turkish perhaps??) so I cannot understand what it is trying to explain. So I'm afraid your question is quite confusing, because you haven't provided the exact error message, you haven't provided relevant source code, and it's generally unclear what is supposed to happen.

Comment: @ADyson How do I send you a private message?

Comment: You can't. This site doesn't have a private messaging facility. The whole point of the site is to provide information to which is helpful to everyone in the future, not just you only. Therefore, everything is done publicly. What do you want to say to me which needs to be said in private? We can continue to discuss your problem right here. Please provide updated information as I have requested, then I (and maybe others who see this post) can try to help you.

Comment: P.S. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example provides a good guide about how to provide the correct information in a question. You need to give me enough code (and sample data, where relevant) to be able to reproduce the problem (or at least follow the structure of it so I can see all the code which is called from when you start your script to when the error occurs, even if I can't actually execute it)

Comment: @ADyson ok you're right, i'm sharing the library like this.

Comment: **StokKontrolDetay =** https://ideone.com/9TXYVi
**ApiClient =** https://ideone.com/B4dIcc
**Library =** https://ideone.com/TipZar
**example =** https://ideone.com/aB565k

Comment: **All extensions of the library are here :** https://github.com/agtt/epttavm-integration

Comment: Ok. But still in that code the ApiClient class does not have any method called StokFiyatGuncelleV3 or StokFiyatGuncelleV2. It just **doesn't exist**. So you cannot call any such method. And you still haven't provided the full error message or context for your code, and it's still unclear how the SoapClient block is related to this, because that doesn't have any methods with those names either, and thus it's unclear how the `$client` object in your 2nd and 3rd code blocks (in the question) gets created. Could _you_ understand this problem if it wasn't your code? I doubt it.

Comment: Please start again with your question and create something which actually makes sense to someone who has not seen it before. I am worried you do not really understand much of it yourself either, which might be part of the problem. Go back to the beginning and re-create your question one step at a time, so that it actually demonstrates a definable, traceable, understandable problem. Right now it's a collection of unrelated out-of-context code snippets, incomplete error messages and links to GitHub pages which themselves are either irrelevant or incomplete.

Comment: @ADyson I updated my question again :)

Comment: ok thanks. But that's basically back to your original question, and I've already explained how to fix that error. Did you attempt to fix it yet, or not?

Comment: @ADyson I tried, but I couldn't. `foreach($stokKontrolListesi as $list){ StokFiyatGuncelleV3('$list->Fiyat','$list->Stok') }` should i try something like. I'm getting close but I don't get results :(

Comment: Huh? That's nothing to do with the error as far as I can see. To fix the stated error message you must first create an instance of `StokKontrolDetay` (e.g. using `new StokKontrolDetay` and then populate it, and then use that variable to pass to the `StokFiyatGuncelleV3` method. Maybe you should read https://www.w3resource.com/php/classes-objects/php-object-oriented-programming.php#createclass